# How to export SPARQL query result to csv?

Tags: java, sparql, rdf, jena, semantic-web

I have an rdf file which looks somewhat like this (but it is actually larger):

```
@prefix skos-xl: <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#> .
@prefix dct:   <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
@prefix adms:  <http://www.w3.org/ns/adms#> .
@prefix esco:  <http://data.europa.eu/esco/model#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix org:   <http://www.w3.org/ns/org#> .
@prefix iso-thes: <http://purl.org/iso25964/skos-thes#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix skos:  <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix prov:  <http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#> .
@prefix foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .


<http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/238343b1-7b51-42b3-a9ed-cf24d3a236e7>
        a                       skos:Concept , esco:MemberConcept , esco:Skill ;
        esco:referenceLanguage  "en"^^xsd:language ;
        esco:skillReuseLevel    <http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill-reuse-level/transversal> ;
        esco:skillType          <http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill-type/skill> ;
        dct:description         <http://data.europa.eu/esco/node-literal/447a21ac-f4e0-41e1-a478-1b7cd4c29af8> , <http://data.europa.eu/esco/node-literal/d9f98a36-44fb-4318-bfd9-6ac6b520b034> ;
        iso-thes:status         "released" ;
        skos:altLabel           "reconocer las carencias en competencias digitales"@es , "bearnaí maidir le cumas digiteach a aithint"@ga , "identificere manglende digitale kundskaber"@da , "digitale vaardigheidskloven identificeren"@nl , "detectar las deficiencias en competencias digitales"@es , "behoeften aan digitale vaardigheden herkennen"@nl , "παροχή υποστήριξης για την αντιμετώπιση ελλείψεων όσον αφορά την ψηφιακή ικανότητα"@el , "detectar las lagunas en competencias digitales"@es , "tunnistaa digitaalisten taitojen puutteet"@fi , "Lücken bei den IKT-Kompetenzen erkennen"@de ;
        skos:broader            <http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/7e5147d1-60b1-4a68-804b-1f5cb0396b91> ;
        skos:broaderTransitive  <http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/7e5147d1-60b1-4a68-804b-1f5cb0396b91> ;
        skos:inScheme           <http://data.europa.eu/esco/concept-scheme/skill-ict-groups> ;
        skos:prefLabel          "digitale vaardigheidskloven herkennen"@nl , "εντοπισμός ελλείψεων όσον αφορά την ψηφιακή ικανότητα"@el , [...] .
```

I have been reading a lot on the topic, but still I dont quite understand how I could convert this file to csv (or even JSON would do) with Java. So far I have been using the following script to extract all triples that exist in a graph and print them out in a console:

```
package semanticweb;

import org.apache.jena.query.Query;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import org.apache.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import org.apache.jena.query.ResultSet;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getData();
    }

    static void getData(){

        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel() ;
        model.read("C:/Users/andri/eclipse-workspace/semanticweb/ict_skills_collection.ttl");

        String queryString = "PREFIX skos-xl: <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#>" +
                "PREFIX dct:   <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>" +
                "PREFIX adms:  <http://www.w3.org/ns/adms#>" +
                "PREFIX esco:  <http://data.europa.eu/esco/model#>" +
                "PREFIX rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>" +
                "PREFIX org:   <http://www.w3.org/ns/org#>"+
                "PREFIX iso-thes: <http://purl.org/iso25964/skos-thes#>"+
                "PREFIX xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>" +
                "PREFIX skos:  <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>" +
                "PREFIX rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>" +
                "PREFIX prov:  <http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#>"+
                "PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>" +  
                "SELECT *"+
                 "WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }"; 


        Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);

        try {

         ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
         while(results.hasNext()) {
             QuerySolution qsol = results.nextSolution();
             System.out.println(qsol.toString());
         }
        }
            finally {
                qexec.close();
            }   


    }

}
```

The console output looks somewhat like this:

```
( ?p = <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel> ) ( ?o = "Defizite bei der digitalen Kompetenz ermitteln"@de ) ( ?s = <http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/238343b1-7b51-42b3-a9ed-cf24d3a236e7> ) -> [Root]
( ?p = <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel> ) ( ?o = "identifikovat nedostatky v digitalnych kompetenciach"@sk ) ( ?s = <http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/238343b1-7b51-42b3-a9ed-cf24d3a236e7> ) -> [Root]
( ?p = <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel> ) ( ?o = "identificar lacunas nas competencias digitais"@pt ) ( ?s = <http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/238343b1-7b51-42b3-a9ed-cf24d3a236e7> ) -> [Root]
```

Does anyone know how I could proceed in converting this triple format to csv? Do I need to understand what these triples represent exactly in order to do this? I appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: It's not a triple format but a resultset which in fact is what a `SELECT` query is supposed to return. If you want triples, you have to use a `CONSTRUCT` query.

Comment: Not sure if your query remains an `s p o` query or will be different, but if you want to convert the `ResultSet` to CSV, then [`ResultSetFormatter.outputAsCSV`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/ResultSetFormatter.html#outputAsCSV-java.io.OutputStream-boolean-) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the something like:

```
public void writemodel(OntModel model) {
    model.write(System.out, "JSON-LD");
    model.write(System.out, "RDF/JSON");
}
```

To write your resultSet you can use

```
ResultSetFormatter.outputAsCSV(OutputStream, resultSet);
ResultSetFormatter.outputAsJSON(OutputStream, resultSet);
```